# Плавный переход-трансформация блоков друг в друга

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Есть блоки внутри контейнера:один -ссылка link, второй-контент content. Как сделать,чтобы при наведении на link, он плавно трансформировался в контент, а при убирании курсива content плавно переходил обратно в link? Желательно без js

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="link" style="background-color:red;width:200px;height:100px;"></div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color:green;width:200px;height:300px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: _плавно трансформировался в контент_ - что здесь имеется ввиду?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.link:hover + .content{
    opacity: 1;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition: 3.5s;
    z-index: 3;
}

.link:not(:hover) + .content{
    opacity: 0;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition: 3.5s;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <div class="link"></div>
     <div class="content"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Нужно, чтобы работало только при наведении на красный блок

Comment: Сейчас при наведении на красный блок он становится зелёным, а при уводе курсора в сторону он превращается опять в красный. Надо, чтобы оставался зелёным?

Comment: Если так, то без JS не обойтись.

Comment: Вы попробуйте навести чуть ниже красного блока и увидите в чем проблема

Comment: Баг пофиксила, проверьте.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.content:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <div class="link"></div>
     <div class="content"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Нужно не изменять прозрачность, а именно заменить блок другим, так как у них разные высоты, если вы внимательно смотрели вопрос

Comment: @ArturHan, ты тогда правь вопрос и опиши подробнее, как и что ты пытался реализовать, если нет такового хотя бы подробнее опиши желаемый результат. Тут гадалок нет...  Как понять,  ***`Как сделать,чтобы при наведении на link, он плавно трансформировался в контент, `***

Comment: вы прописали одинаковую высоту блоков в стилях, а у меня в вопросе уже задана разная высота! При разной высоте блоков ваш код не будет работать

Comment: Сори, не досмотрел про высоту блока. Однако, работать всё равно будет, только не так как надо Вам, видимо... А как надо Вам?

Comment: Нужно,чтобы при наведении четко на блок,он трансформировался, а с вашим кодом при разной высоте он будет синеть уже при наведении ниже, так как синий блок больше по высоте